# Hexadecimal value not being written correctly to a char using scanf

Tags: c, char, hex, printf, scanf

I am programming in C and using `scanf` to write two values to two different variables and then output that using `printf`. However, when I type the first of the two values, it just comes back as `($00)`. The second value seems to work fine however, and will report back what I typed. I'm assuming this is just a `scanf` problem. Here is a part of the code where the problem takes place. Why could this be?

```c
intA = strcmp(command, "write");
if(intA != 0) intA = strcmp(command, "w");
if(intA == 0){
    printf("location to write to, value> ");
    scanf(" %x %x", &charA, &charB);
    ram[charA] = charB;
    printf("($%.2x): $%.2x\n\n", charA, ram[charA]);
}
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `charA` and `charB`, and the input. What is the significance of the `32` restriction in `%32x`?

Comment: `charA` and `charB` are declared as global variables as `unsigned char`. Also, I didn't mean to put that, but removing the 32 character restriction still yields the same result.

Comment: Please post the information as a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. You cannot use `%x` with type `char`. The `%x` expects the target variable to be of `int` or `unsigned int` type. The `32` is absurd: not even a 64-bit variable can hold 32 (hexadecimal) digits. What is the input you are trying to scan, and what should the result be?

Comment: What do you expect `"$%.2d"` to do? You can't convert to decimal notation in that way. It looks as though you are taking wild guesses as to what the code should be. You can't code like this.

Comment: I'm trying to scan for two one byte hexadecimal input, and it will simply print the changed values in the array. `%.2x` will pad the hexadecimal output with zeros.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `%x`, which is for reading an unsigned int.  Apparently you are trying to read values of type unsigned **char**.  So you need a length modifier.
Try this:

```
scanf("%hhx%hhx", &charA, &charB);
```

Without the `hh` modifier, `scanf` will write an int's worth of bytes (probably 2 or 4) on top of `charA` and `charB`, thus clobbering some nearby memory.

Specifically: you said "when I type the first of the two values, it just comes back as 00. The second value seems to work fine however".  So if you type, say, `12` for your location and `34` for your value, `scanf` is trying to write either `0034` or `00000034` into `charB`, and the extra `00`'s are spilling over on top of `charA`.  (That's *after* `scanf` tried to write either `0012` or `00000012` into `charA`, which similarly spilled over and overwrote something else.)

Alternatively, you could declare your `charA` and `charB` variables as being of type `unsigned int`, instead.  There's not much to be gained in making them characters.  (And, as we've seen, there's something to be lost!)